# Generic interface and union type on nested interface

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type that allows me to define a prop (for a react component):

```
type RV<T> = {
    base: T;
    tablet?: T;
    desktop?: T;
};

export type ResponsiveValue<T> = RV<T> | T;
```

This works fine for strings, numbers and booleans, meaning I can use

```
backgroundUrl: ResponsiveValue<string>
```

And I can pass in `backgroundUrl` either as string or as the interface (where the values are string). All cool.

If I do the same with an interface, instead

```
type StaticImageData = {
    src: string;
    height: number;
    width: number;
    blurDataURL?: string;
};

export type ImageProps = {
  imageData: ResponsiveValue<StaticImageData>;
};
```

And I try to `if (imageData.base)` I get the good old typescript error:

`Property 'base' does not exist on type 'ResponsiveValue<StaticImageData>'.   Property 'base' does not exist on type 'StaticImageData'`

How can I fix the `ResponsiveValue` type definition to make it work with interfaces as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the type of typguard you are using to be an `in` type guard:

```
declare const imageData: ResponsiveValue<StaticImageData>;

if ('base' in imageData) {
    imageData.base
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASgagHgCoD4oF4oG8CwAoKQqAIwEMBnCALiiQG58iphTiAbCYAfhvsaIAmEcgGtgAezA9aDPAF9Z+CAA8w4gE7Bm4aDGFqAduQCWANwhxSbAK4RkaTPHtQAPjPwe8oSFADKLYGMAYwBJAFtSAHMIABFSFgxsfkJydSCacmB1YwNI2SYACwhjSILgGgNrMOIIdXyiAHdjAWACiqqauuSSG3U4lgBVGAAZaUzs3NkFTxU1TW0fcKiIAAV1SXJE3AIoYwjo-tIaPXJDE3NLGzt-eOClg-jSFCnZISC2UnVoIPEjLT3lodjvpfucLFZbAgboFQvtYo9np5jAAzKAACgA5GRKBjdgZdnDDgBKJI7QgAh4sAB02Ig+DkQA)